# How can I retrieve the istio ingress gateway hosts for an HPE Ezmeral Container Platform managed cluster?

Tags: istio-gateway, hpe-container-platform, ezmeral

I have configured a K8S cluster with istio-ingressgateway as per the [docs](https://docs.containerplatform.hpe.com/53/reference/kubernetes/kubernetes-administrator/clusters/cluster-add-ons/Istio_Service_Mesh.html).

Although the HPE Container Platform managed haproxy gateway can route traffic to the istio-ingressgateway, I would like to access the host endpoints directly.

How can I determine the ingress IP addresses and ports for the hosts avoiding the managed haproxy gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I found the information:

```
$ kubectl get po -l istio=ingressgateway -n istio-system \
     -o jsonpath='{.items[*].status.hostIP}'
10.1.0.193 10.1.0.132 10.1.0.174
```

the ports are found as follows:

```
$ kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway \
     -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="http2")].nodePort}'
32725

$ kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway \
     -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="https")].nodePort}'
30557

$ kubectl -n istio-system get service istio-ingressgateway \
     -o jsonpath='{.spec.ports[?(@.name=="tcp")].nodePort}'
[no data returned]
```

Source: [istio docs](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/ingress-control/#determining-the-ingress-ip-and-ports)